# resx resource file shows warning "The resource name is not a valid identifier"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resources, resx

### Background

- I began converting strings to resources for within application.
- They all worked fine.
- My PC restarted itself without warning (power issue).

### Problem

- Four resources within my RESX file trigger a warning along the lines of:

  > The resource name '[name]' is not a valid identifier.

Where [name] is the name of the resource.

### Screen capture

[image]

I can't find what I'm doing wrong, and I can't determine whether this is related to my other power failure issue.

I know resource names shouldn't contain spaces or periods, but I've checked mine and I don't think they do (PS I know the names could be much better, and do plan to reviswit it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot start your resource name with a number.

Comment: D'oh! Thank you. Pattern should have been more obvious after I cropped the screenshot. :)

Answer (score 6):

Actually in the Resx designer, if you change the "**Access Modifier" dropdown, to "No code generation**", the designer.cs and the warning "The resource name '[name]' is not a valid identifier." go away.

Unless the designer cs is necessary for you to have, you can try this approach as well.